# Connect to external subversion repository via mac and host a xcode project

Tags: xcode, macos, svn, repository, code-sharing

I have made a free private subversion repository at assembla.com. Now i want to host my project to this repository or in layman terms i want to put my xcode project in this repository so that only my colleague is able to use this project at his own place. I want this to be setup on mac. I know that we have to use terminal and put some commands but i do not know the procedure after setting up an external subversion repository. Could someone please explain me the steps and list the tools needed to connect to this repo from my mac? (so that my colleague can use it too?)

Answer (score 0):

You need some third-party subversion management tools. I prefer `SourceTree` but you can also read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899/best-subversion-client-for-mac-os .

Online code repository will provide an address for you to clone/push. Just paste it into your subversion tools then tool will clone it automatically. That's quite easy after you read each site's instruction.

PS: Command line is not a must since there's already many nice GUI tools. Just use command line for some advance functions or by shell scripts.